# How to use custom cross validation folds with XGBoost

Tags: r, xgboost

I'm using the R wrapper for XGBoost. In the function *xgb.cv*, there is a `folds` parameter with the description

> list provides a possibility of using a list of pre-defined CV folds
>   (each element must be a vector of fold's indices). If folds are
>   supplied, the nfold and stratified parameters would be ignored.

So, do I just specify the indices for training the model and assume the rest will be for testing?  For example, if my training data is something like

```
    Feature1 Feature2 Target
 1:        2       10     10
 2:        7        1      9
 3:        8        2      3
 4:        8       10      7
 5:        8        2      9
 6:        3        7      3
```

and I want to cross validate using (train, test) indices as ((1,2,3), (4,5,6)) and ((4,5,6), (1,2,3)) do I set `folds=list(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6))`?

Comment: One of `caret::createFolds` or `caret::createDataPartition` would do the hard work for you. Your example is probably correct.

Answer (score 4):

Through some trial and error I figured out that `xgboost` is using the passed indices as indices of the *test* folds.  Confirmed this by noticing the current devel version of `xgboost` explicitly states it in the [documentation](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/R-package/man/xgb.cv.Rd#L67).

Comment: custom folds are giving results very different than regular CV. To describe what I am doing: the `xgb.DMatrix` has 2000 rows. `folds` should have test indices. So, `folds=list(1000:2000, 1500:2000, 1750:2000)`. It is doing in-the-bag predictions...

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example for both generating the folds and using them.

Assume in our dataframe we have a column of ids, such that we want to put all rows with a given id value in a fold.

The code below

- finds the unique ids
- preallocates a list for the folds
- iterates over ids, creating lists of row indices that match

  `fold.ids <- unique(df$id)
  custom.folds <- vector("list", length(fold.ids))
  i <- 1
  for( id in fold.ids){
    custom.folds[[i]] <- which( df$id %in% id )
    i <- i+1
    }`

Here is an example using the above fold list in `xgb.cv`

`res <- xgb.cv(param, dtrain, nround, folds=custom.folds, prediction = TRUE)`

Reasonable values for other `xgb.cv` parameters can be [found in the documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xgboost/xgboost.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

This worked best for me:

```
custom.folds <- caret::createFolds(data$Label, k=10, list=T)

xgbcv <- xgb.cv(
  params = params
  ,data = df
  ,maximize = F
  ,prediction = T
  ,metrics = "logloss"
  ,folds = custom.folds
)
```