# incorrect fold specification with XGBoost

Tags: r, xgboost

Specifying `folds` in `xgb.cv` is producing abnormal results. Probably it is wrongly specified.
For example, with `nfolds` option:

```
params=list(booster = "gbtree" #'dart'
            ,objective="binary:logistic",eta=0.1 
            ,gamma=0., max_depth=4, min_child_weight=4
            ,subsample=1 , colsample_bytree=.8
            ,scale_pos_weight=1.5)
xgbcv=xgb.cv(params=params,data=dm0z,nrounds=300
             ,nfold=5, stratified = T ,print_every_n = 300        
             ,early_stopping_rounds = 50, maximize = T
             ,feval=xgb.f1,showsd=T)
[1] train-f1:0.465200+0.075877  test-f1:0.351000+0.083888 
Multiple eval metrics are present. Will use test_f1 for early stopping.
Will train until test_f1 hasn't improved in 50 rounds.

Stopping. Best iteration:
[29]    train-f1:0.703000+0.009143  test-f1:0.481400+0.026227
```

Acording to this OP [How to use custom cross validation folds with XGBoost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38287223/how-to-use-custom-cross-validation-folds-with-xgboost), one should give test indexes for each CV. So:

```
casos=nrow(dm0z)
ts1=seq(1000,125,-125)
cvt=lapply(ts1, function(x) (casos-x):casos)
str(cvt)
List of 8
 $ : int [1:1001] 1275 1276 1277 1278 1279 1280 1281 1282 1283 1284 ...
 $ : int [1:876] 1400 1401 1402 1403 1404 1405 1406 1407 1408 1409 ...
 $ : int [1:751] 1525 1526 1527 1528 1529 1530 1531 1532 1533 1534 ...
 $ : int [1:626] 1650 1651 1652 1653 1654 1655 1656 1657 1658 1659 ...
 $ : int [1:501] 1775 1776 1777 1778 1779 1780 1781 1782 1783 1784 ...
 $ : int [1:376] 1900 1901 1902 1903 1904 1905 1906 1907 1908 1909 ...
 $ : int [1:251] 2025 2026 2027 2028 2029 2030 2031 2032 2033 2034 ...
 $ : int [1:126] 2150 2151 2152 2153 2154 2155 2156 2157 2158 2159 ...
xgbcv=xgb.cv(params=params,data=dm0z,nrounds=300
             ,folds=cvt
             ,print_every_n = 50, early_stopping_rounds = 50, maximize = T
             ,feval=xgb.f1,showsd=T)
[1] train-f1:0.661125+0.022707  test-f1:0.662000+0.036455 
Multiple eval metrics are present. Will use test_f1 for early stopping.
Will train until test_f1 hasn't improved in 50 rounds.

[51]    train-f1:0.881375+0.011683  test-f1:0.890500+0.044869 
[101]   train-f1:0.925750+0.011289  test-f1:0.932500+0.038665 
[151]   train-f1:0.954875+0.007184  test-f1:0.955000+0.035391 
[201]   train-f1:0.971250+0.005333  test-f1:0.969750+0.030330 
[251]   train-f1:0.981625+0.003426  test-f1:0.978750+0.028573 
[300]   train-f1:0.988750+0.002437  test-f1:0.983000+0.027404
```

Probably, `xgb.cv` is doing prediction "in-the-bag" (test-f1 ~= train-f1), and `folds` is incorrect.

obs1:  `xgb.f1` calculates de F1-score

```
xgb.f1=function(preds, dtrain) {
  labels=getinfo(dtrain, "label")
  x=Metrica(labels,preds)$f1
  return(list(metric="f1", value=x))}
```

Answer (score 0):

the question is how `xgb.cv` select the train subsets.
 It does `slice(dall, unlist(folds[-k]))`, i.e., selects all other tests indices data:

```
...
...
bst_folds <- lapply(seq_along(folds), function(k) {
    dtest <- slice(dall, folds[[k]])
    dtrain <- slice(dall, unlist(folds[-k])) #this line
    handle <- xgb.Booster.handle(params, list(dtrain, dtest))
    list(dtrain = dtrain, bst = handle,
         watchlist = list(train = dtrain,test = dtest), index = folds[[k]])
  })
...
...
```

Supposing that, when you give the test rows, the train rows are the others, the solution is to change that line to
 `dtrain <- slice(dall, setdiff(1:nrow(dall),folds[[k]]))`