# Tuning xgboost with xgb.train providing a validation set in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation, xgboost

Related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433458/how-to-specify-train-and-test-indices-for-xgb-cv-in-r-package-xgboost) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199780/why-is-it-that-xgb-cv-performs-well-but-xgb-train-does-not). The common way of tuning xgboost (i.e. nrounds) is using xgb.cv that performs k-fold cross validation, for example:

```
require(xgboost)
data(iris)
set.seed(1)
index = sample(1:150)
X = as.matrix(iris[index, 1:4])
y = as.matrix(as.numeric(iris[index, "Species"])) - 1
param = list(eta=0.1, objective="multi:softprob")
xgb.cv(params=param, data=X, nrounds=50, nfold=5, label=y, num_class=3)
> train.merror.mean train.merror.std test.merror.mean test.merror.std
> 1:          0.021667         0.009501         0.040000        0.043461
> 2:          0.018333         0.006972         0.033333        0.047141
> 3:          0.018333         0.006972         0.033333        0.047141
> 4:          0.018333         0.006972         0.033333        0.047141
```

Anyway, I want to tune xgboost providing a validation set. This is not possible using `xgb.cv`. It seems that this can be achieved using `xgb.train`:

```
require(xgboost)
data(iris)
set.seed(1)
index = sample(1:150)
indexTrain = index[1:100]
indexValid = index[101:150]
Xtrain = as.matrix(iris[indexTrain, 1:4])
Xvalid = as.matrix(iris[indexValid, 1:4])
yTrain = as.numeric(iris[indexTrain, "Species"]) - 1
yValid = as.numeric(iris[indexValid, "Species"]) - 1
train = xgb.DMatrix(Xtrain, label=yTrain)
valid = xgb.DMatrix(Xvalid, label=yValid)
param = list(eta=0.1, objective="multi:softprob")
watchlist = list(eval=valid, train=train)
model = xgb.train(params=param, data=train, nround=40, watchlist=watchlist,
                  num_class=3)
>[0]    eval-merror:0.060000    train-merror:0.020000
>[1]    eval-merror:0.060000    train-merror:0.030000
>[2]    eval-merror:0.060000    train-merror:0.020000
>[3]    eval-merror:0.060000    train-merror:0.020000
```

In fact, while training using xgb.traing it's possible to observe the evaluation error printed in the console. Anyway, it seems that this information is lost since the only attributes of `model` are `handle` and `raw`.

QUESTION 1: How to retrieve the vector of the validation error printed in the console?

QUESTION 2: How to retrieve the vector of the standard error of the individual validation errors such as the once produced by `xgb.cv`?

EDIT1: In lines 58 and 59 [here](https://www.kaggle.com/nigelcarpenter/liberty-mutual-group-property-inspection-prediction/r-xgboost-with-gini-eval-and-stopping/code) it seems that the author is able to extract the validation error. Anyway, I'm not able to adapt to do the same with the iris dataset.

EDIT2: Another (unanswered) strictly related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38287223/how-to-use-custom-cross-validation-folds-with-xgboost)